# RSACryptoServiceProvider in Node js

Tags: c#, node.js, signature

I have to sign a string in node js, in the same way of a C# application, which uses RSACryptoServiceProvider. In fact it uses

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("file.pfx", "aPassword", 
X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)RSACryptoServiceProvider.Create();
rsa.FromXmlString(certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
signer = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
signer.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

byte[] signedData = signer.CreateSignature("a string");
string signedString = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
```

I've tried to do the same in node js, so far, using jsonwebtoken in this way

```
var kdrPrivateKey = fs.readFileSync('private_key.pem');
var authorizationSigned = jwt.sign("a string", kdrPrivateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
var authorizationBase64 = Base64.encode(authorizationSigned);
```

I also got the private_key from file.pfx in this way

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -nocerts -out private_key.pem -nodes
```

My question, finally is, is the node js code equivalent to the C# code? If not, how can I make the C# code in a node js way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use RSA XML Decrypter for Node. Decrypt a string by private RSA XML C# key in Node.js.

```
var RSAXML = require('rsa-xml'),

// base64 encoded private rsa xml key
var privateKey1 = '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';
var encBase64_1 = '4TkhLlVNK27LQXSRIftGCbwOI2qnBGD0eR61g53KAdw5J+BTpczLpdWGn/9v3I6xGPQYvTB1F2cmbcuBboNGa18b+8gigwbat9vTEuLjD/OKl2V+jpqKf3xxwYYuz1s05HyV8KWxbS01M/iwjWPrcNRWh3vWff9pRAu8Z6KQAQc=';
var privateKey2 = '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';
var encBase64_2 = '4TkhLlVNK27LQXSRIftGCbwOI2qnBGD0eR61g53KAdw5J+BTpczLpdWGn/9v3I6xGPQYvTB1F2cmbcuBboNGa18b+8gigwbat9vTEuLjD/OKl2V+jpqKf3xxwYYuz1s05HyV8KWxbS01M/iwjWPrcNRWh3vWff9pRAu8Z6KQAQc=';

var rsa = new RSAXML();
// a private key
rsa.importKey(privateKey1, 'pKey1');
var decrypted1 = rsa.decrypt(encBase64_1, 'pKey1');
console.log('decrypted:', decrypted1);

// another private key
rsa.importKey(privateKey2, 'pKey2');
var decrypted2 = rsa.decrypt(encBase64_2, 'pKey2');
console.log('decrypted:', decrypted2);
```